# CoreData saving object is not successful

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to update `int` data by using `CoreData` but I think I am missing some parts before updating the object. Here what I am trying to do to save the `int` value. Here I want to both save and update only first object value.

```
- (IBAction)btnYakClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kalorimetre" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSManagedObject* kaloriObject = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    NSNumber *valWeek = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:300];
    NSNumber *valMonth = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1000];

    [kaloriObject setValue:valWeek forKey:@"thisweek"];
    [kaloriObject setValue:valWeek forKey:@"thismonth"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the line where you're saving it. For example:

```
NSError *saveError;

if (![context save:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", saveError, [saveError localizedDescription]);
}
```

It might also be a good idea to limit the fetch request since you're only looking for the first object:

```
[request setFetchLimit:1];
```

I would hope that this would improve performance but cannot confirm.

Comment: ohh my bad. Thanks a lot it. very tough day and now very little mistakes :)